# How to get Kohana session in 3rd party script?

Tags: php, kohana

I have an Kohana 3.3.3 application and few 3rd party scripts in subfolder. When I login in my Kohana app session 'logged_in' is being set to true. I want to check if logged_in is true outside Kohana app.

I tried this solution: [How to get kohana session data outside kohana application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623615/how-to-get-kohana-session-data-outside-kohana-application)
But with this code Im unable to login on my root app.

Is there any way to access Kohana session?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the type of session you use in Kohana. Assuming that this is `native`, then you must know its name minimally and then:

```php
session_name('your session name');
session_start();
```

Although it is best to implement the whole: https://koseven.ga/documentation/api/Session_Native#_read

An additional problem may be the encryption of session data, but it is also possible to overcome: https://koseven.ga/documentation/api/Session#read